# My phone is 'samsumg s2 plus' i wana root my phone

Tags: rooting, root-access

Am using samsumg s2 plus. I wanna root my phone. Suggests me best way.

Already tryed the www.unlockroot.com website.  But I failed. 
Help me ..

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2663834

Comment: Thax... rooting is done

Comment: @RossC / Yazz: Mind to create an answer with at least an abstract, so we can link this question from our index for future users?

Comment: @Izzy whoops! Didn't see the *plus*

Comment: @bmdixon Thought so. Also had to look twice. Luckily, our index has two questions linked on different S2 models, so I wanted to check which one it is – only then I noticed. Had there been only one link, I'd fallen for the same :) Nevertheless, we no longer dupe-VTC against the list. If it has a matching entry, dupe-VTC against that instead – otherwise, link it from there (which I will do now, as this one at least has a pointer – hopefully Ross will make his suggestion an answer soon).

Comment: @Izzy answer posted now!

Comment: @RossC Wow – that deserves an immediate +1 from me, very detailed – thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### Rooting the Samsung Galaxy S2 **Plus**

[Here is a Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RM7lxd7fDqk) with the steps to root the device, below are the written instructions I've modified this from the [XDA post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2663834) for grammar etc.

**Prerequisites**:

- Android 4.2.2 (If you want to flash custom rom ||| if not 4.1.2 is okay)
- You can flash 4.2.2 via [odin](/questions/tagged/odin)  find your firmware at [Sam Mobile](http://www.sammobile.com)
- USB Cable
- Samsung USB Drivers
- Odin 3.07 (Flashing Tool)(http://d-h.st/hSj)
- CWM Recovery I9105/P(http://d-h.st/oKe) (Android 4.1.2)
- CWM Recovery I9105P(http://d-h.st/II4) (Android 4.2.2)
- CWM Recovery I9105(http://d-h.st/bq8) (Android 4.2.2)
- Root Package(http://download.chainfire.eu/) - Locate most up to date SuperSU Zip.

**Rooting the device:**

- Open Odin 3.07.exe
- Put your phone into `Download Mode`
  (Power button - Home button - Volume down button,at same time)
- When you enter in Download Mod, you should get blue box on Odin 3.07
- Uncheck  `Auto Reboot option`
- Go to PDA and find your recovery, then click on OK
- After you checked everything click on Start
- It should take around up to 30 - 40 seconds
- When its finished take out battery, put it again
- Go to recovery mode
  (Power button - Home button - Volume up button,at the same time)
- Navigate with Volume Rockers (Volume Up -  Volume Down)
- Select via Power Button
- Go to install zip from sdcard ( if you putted in your phone)
- Go to install zip from sdcard/sdcard1 (if you putted on sdcard)
- Find root package, and install it via pressing power button
- Go back and reboot system now

DONE !
You have rooted your s2 plus !