# Rooting and uprading Galaxy SL GT-I9003 to ICS or Jelly Bean

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, rooting, 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-sl

There are lots of howtos online but most of them are old with rotten links (to the downloads). In addition to how to root and upgrade and where to download the files, I'd like to know the following:

1. Is the (ICS or Jelly Bean) kernel I need to download trustworthy (i.e. open source)?
2. Are there any bugs associated with the kernel?

My phone is not rooted and is running firmware version 2.2.1 and kernel version 2.6.32.9.

Comment: Reza, not sure you've picked the right identification: Are you sure it's an "S2" *and* "GT-I1003*? The 1003 looks a bit weird here. We've got 2 links in our [rooting index](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/16575) for the S2: [Galaxy S2 GT-I9100P](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/28662/16575) / [GT-I9100G](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/22768/16575), and one for the [Galaxy S2 plus](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/82582/16575). Does any of those match?

Comment: Ah – OK, but isn't that the "Galaxy **SL**" then? S2 is 9100. Check: Yepp, here you go: [Galaxy SL GT i9003](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/32461/16575)